# How to modify TXM file (TX Text Control)

Tags: vb6, txtextcontrol

I have sources of an old VB6 application from 2006. I was asked to change some email templates. I found they are stored as TXM files, plus we also have correspondent DOT files with fields which probably were used to create TXM files.

The VB6 build machine has TXWords 1.63 installed in 2006. But it cannot open TXM files (does not support that extension).

I downloaded latest trial for TX Text Control Words. It can open TXM file and allows me to modify it, but not save it back as TXM.

Please advise how do I suppose to modify TXM files or any way to create TXM from DOT?

Comment: It's anybody's guess, but it might not let you save files in the trial version, especially if it's an old control.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I figured out. I need to use program that comes as a sample to TX Text Control v13. When TX Text Control installed it's located at "c:\Program Files\The Imaging Source Europe GmbH\TX Text Control 13.0\Samples\VB6\MDI". It allows to modify TXM files, add images to template and convert Word documents to TXM.

The only mystery for me why the original programmer couldn't use PDF file with fields, cause after all the application creates PDF from TXM.